# How to represent the mysql database in graph form in android?

Tags: php, android, mysql, graph

I am trying to implement the graph representation of the database.I am using php for accessing the database.I dont know how to do that.

Comment: please put your code whatever u have done in the question

Answer (score 1):

First you need to decide what kind of graph that you want to draw. Select a mobile friendly JavaScript library that can draw the graph that you want.
Read it's documentation and generate HTTP response that can be used as input to the JavaScript library that you use. You can use PHP for that.
Use WebView (http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) to you graph to your application.